# PHPUnit Symfony set IP address for the client

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I need to test behavior of the feature which depends on the users IP address. The user should be redirected to different pages depending on his IP address. 
I create client like that: `$this->client = static::createClient();`

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to create different clients:

`$this->client1 = static::createClient([], ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '11.11.11.11']);
 $this->client2 = static::createClient([], ['REMOTE_ADDR' => '22.22.22.22']);`